# VBA namespace in createElement

Tags: xml, vba, namespaces

Trying to add a namespace before the Element but getting the error "Only a default namespace can have an empty URI".
My code is quite simple:

```
nmsp = "http://test.com"
    Set root = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "ns1:currency_rates", nmsp)
    doc.appendChild root

    Set ydatasNode = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "ns1:currency_rate", nmsp)
    root.appendChild ydatasNode

    ' ITERATE CLIENT NODES '
     For i = 2 To 3
       
        ' FIRST NAME NODE '
        Set firstNameNode = doc.createElement("inst_id")
        firstNameNode.Text = "1001"
        ydatasNode.appendChild firstNameNode
```

It generates XML as

```
<ns1:currency_rates xmlns:ns1="http://test.com">
    <ns1:currency_rate>
        <inst_id>1001</inst_id>
        <lastName></lastName>
        <age></age>
        <civility yid="AAAA"></civility>
        <inst_id>1001</inst_id>
        <lastName></lastName>
        <age></age>
        <civility yid="AAAA"></civility>
    </ns1:currency_rate>
</ns1:currency_rates>
```

what I need is to have

```
<ns1:inst_id>1001</ns1:inst_id>
```

If I'm trying with
`Set firstNameNode = doc.createElement("ns1:inst_id")`
i have an error: "Only default namespace can have empty URI"
If I try like this
`Set firstNameNode = doc.createElement("ns1:inst_id", "uri")`  - "Wrong number of arguments passed" So probably it needs override the method but not sure how to do this

Comment: Can you show a complete example?  Are you creating a document from scratch?

Comment: I think though when creating a node with a namespace you don't include the namespace alias in the tagname, so try: `doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "ns1:currency_rate", nmsp)`

Comment: Hello have in a code:
Set ydatasNode = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "ns1:currency_rate", nmsp)

Comment: Can you show the starting point? (ie. your XML including namespace declarations)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ident As String = "<ns1:currency_rates xmlns:ns1=""http://test.com""></ns1:currency_rates>"

        Dim rates = XElement.Parse(ident)
        Dim ns1 = rates.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns1")
        rates.Add(New XElement(ns1 + "currency_rate"))
        Dim rate = rates.Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "currency_rate").FirstOrDefault()

        rate.Add(New Object() { _
                 New XElement("inst_id", 1001), _
                 New XElement("lastname"), _
                 New XElement("age"), _
                 New XElement("civility", New XAttribute("yid", "AAAA")), _
                 New XElement("inst_id", 1001), _
                 New XElement("lastname"), _
                 New XElement("age"), _
                 New XElement("civility", New XAttribute("yid", "AAAA")) _
                 })

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This code is for VB.NET and I can't explicitly move it to VBA